# Printing items of an arbitrary sized list

Tags: python, list, function

I have this code:

```
def draw_grid(grid_ref):
    for i in grid_ref:
        print i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], i[4], i[5]

y0 = ['-','-','-','-','-','-']
y1 = ['-','-','-','-','-','-']
y2 = ['-','-','-','-','-','-']
y3 = ['-','-','-','-','-','-']
y4 = ['-','-','-','-','-','-']
y5 = ['-','-','-','-','-','-']
grid = [y0,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5]
draw_grid(grid)
```

Which output is:

```
- - - - - -
- - - - - -
- - - - - -
- - - - - -
- - - - - -
- - - - - -
```

This is what i want, but has some things wrong. And main problem is I cant use `draw_grid` function with bigger or smaller grids. So I have:

```
def grid_gen(x,y):    #Generates a grid of y lists with x items in every list
    row = []
    grid = []
    for i in range(x):
        row.append('-')
    for i in range(y):
        grid.append(row)
    return grid
```

and I cant use `draw_grid` on it.

My question is: how can I improve `draw_grid` function to work properly with any kind of grid and get the same output?

Comment: Maybe try using the star operator? `print(*grid)`?

Comment: @cyphar OP seems to use Python 2.x

Comment: Your `grid_gen` function appends always the same row to your grid.

Comment: @tobias_k People on 2.x should go to the `__future__`

Comment: I know that, @Matthias. It's because i only need that '-' rows. Later they will be modified.

Comment: @DavidP. I think what Matthias wants to point out is that you have the very same object in each row. This means that if you do `grid[0][0] = 'a'` all rows will be affected. Avoid this by appending `row[:]` instead of `row` so you actually get a copy.

Comment: C***P!! Thanks!!!, that would be a struggle when i tried to modify cells!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `' '.join` to join the entire line from the grid with spaces and print it, independently of how many cells it has.

```
def draw_grid(grid_ref):
    for i in grid_ref:
        print(' '.join(i))
```

Also, as noted in comments, your `grid_gen` function will create a list of list, that contains multiple references to *the same* list, i.e. if you change one of them, you change all of them. You can use `[:]` to create a copy of the `row` list before inserting it into the `grid` list of lists.

```
def grid_gen(x,y):
    row = []
    grid = []
    for i in range(x):
        row.append('-')
    for i in range(y):
        grid.append(row[:])
    return grid
```

Or a lot shorter, using a nested list comprehension:

```
def grid_gen(x,y):
    return [['-' for i in range(x)] for k in range(y)]
```

Comment: I believe it is hurtful for the language when people still suggests code only useful on python 2.x.  At least put parenthesis around `print` or use the `print_function` which bring many improvements...

Comment: i will use (and accept) this because is closer to my python knowledge. I don't know a lot about __future__  or print(), but obviously i need to research them. Thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: You can also do `['-']*x` instead of `['-' for i in range(x)]` ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) function:

```
from __future__ import print_function  # Python 2.x

def draw_grid(grid_ref):
    for i in grid_ref:
        print(*i)
```

The default separator is `' '`.

Answer (score 0):

Try string multiplication:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> for x in range(n):
...     print ('- '*n).strip()
... 
- - - - -
- - - - -
- - - - -
- - - - -
- - - - -
>>> n =2
>>> for x in range(n):
...     print ('- '*n).strip()
... 
- -
- -
>>>
```